# "Error in [...] : attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex" problem when trying to run lapply(). Can anyone work with me to debug this?

Tags: r

I currently have this function that returns the mean life expectancy of a given year:

```
get_col_mean <- function(data_frame, column_name){
  return(mean(data_frame[[column_name]], na.rm = TRUE))
}
```

An example of it's use, if I was to run the code:

```
test2 <- get_col_mean(life_exp, "X2000")
```

I receive **67.486**, which is the average life expectancy worldwide in the year 2000.

Now, I am trying to use the following code:

```
col_means <- lapply(life_exp, get_col_mean, paste("X", 1800:2100))
```

To create a **list** of life expectancy means for every year. However, when I try to run this line of code, it gives me error:

```
Error in data_frame[[column_name]] : attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? Also I know that I can solve this using different methods a lot easier (that don't require my function), but for the sake of my assignment, I have to use my function to solve this problem. The assignment wants me to use apply(), lapply(), or sapply() to solve this problem, so if apply() or sapply() would work better than lapply(), let me know that too. Also, if the only way to solve this problem is to alter my function in some way (my function is the problem, not my lapply() code), I am fine with doing so.

I'm trying to attach a picture of what the life_exp data.frame looks like but I can't find any way to do so (first time using this website). In an attempt to explain it, all of the rows represent a country and all of the columns represent a year (X1900 being the year 1900). Row "Afghanistan" + column "X1900" would give a number representing the life expectancy of a person in Afghanistan in the year 1900.

Comment: You can loop over the column names `lapply(paste("X", 1800:2100), function(x) get_col_mean(life_exp, x))`

Comment: As a reproducible example `lapply(names(mtcars)[1:2], function(x) get_col_mean(mtcars, x))` or just `colMeans(mtcars[1:2])`

Comment: I tried doing that back when you commented on my old post but it didn't work for me. I got this error `In mean.default(data_frame[[column_name]], na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA` 301 times. Still created a list though, but it is just filled entirely with value NA.

Comment: That is strange because the `mtcars` example is working fine.  Can you check the `str(life_exp)` may be some columns are not `numeric` class?

Comment: this is what I got for that: `str(life_exp)
'data.frame': 187 obs. of  302 variables:
 $ country: chr  "Afghanistan" "Albania" "Algeria" "Andorra" ...
 $ X1800  : num  28.2 35.4 28.8 NA 27 33.5 33.2 34 34 34.4 ...
 $ X1801  : num  28.2 35.4 28.8 NA 27 33.5 33.2 34 34 34.4 ...` , there are "NA"'s, but I thought I handled that in my function when i put na.rm = TRUE.

Comment: Try `lapply(c("X1800", "X1801"), function(x) get_col_mean(life_exp, x))` from your comments, these two columns are definitely numeric and it should work.  I assume that there are no leading/lagging spaces in column names

Comment: ah never mind, my mistake. You were completely right before but you forgot to put paste0 instead of paste in your explanation. I just changed paste to paste0 and it worked fine. Thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in the OP's code is based on looping the data.frame and not by the column names.

```
lapply(paste0("X", 1800:2100), function(x) get_col_mean(life_exp, x))
```